# how to upload multile user profile pics at a time?

Tags: 7

I have used **user reg with picture** module for uploading user profile picture on registration page but there is option for uploading only one picture at a time .

I am developing social network website there is requirement of uploading multiple user profile pics.

but how its possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like profile2 module and create image upload filed that allows multiple files.

Comment: but i am using avatar approval module for user profile pic which only work with core user profile pics upload cck field  will it work with profile2 module